# JLS as related to type casting

Tags: java, generics, casting

I try to understand more fundamentally type casting in Java but can not understand some parts of JLS.  
In particular this (in the meaning of casting of class type S to class or interface type T):

> Furthermore, if there exists a supertype X of T, and a supertype Y of S, such that both X and Y are provably distinct parameterized types (§4.5), and that the erasures of X and Y are the same, a compile-time error occurs.

and this (in the meaning of casting of interface type S to final class type T):

> Otherwise, S is either a parameterized type that is an invocation of some generic type declaration G, or a raw type corresponding to a generic type declaration G. Then there must exist a supertype X of T, such that X is an invocation of G, or a compile-time error occurs.
>   Furthermore, if S and X are provably distinct parameterized types then a compile-time error occurs.

Maybe someone can give some brief examples to clarify these extracts?

P.S. After a some consideration and guidance from @ErickGHagstrom I think I can give a clarification of these two tricky JLS extracts.

## Extract 1.

JLS says:

> Two parameterized types are provably distinct if either of the following is true:
>
> - They are parameterizations of distinct generic type declarations.
> - Any of their type arguments are provably distinct.

and:

> Two type arguments are provably distinct if one of the following is true:
>
> - Neither argument is a type variable or wildcard, and the two arguments are not the same type.
> - One type argument is a type variable or wildcard, with an upper bound (from capture conversion (§5.1.10), if necessary) of S; and the other type argument T is not a type variable or wildcard; and neither |S| <: |T| nor |T| <: |S| (§4.8, §4.10).
> - Each type argument is a type variable or wildcard, with upper bounds (from capture conversion, if necessary) of S and T; and neither |S| <: |T| nor |T| <: |S|.

Therefore `List<Integer>` and `List<Number>` are provably distinct but `List<? extends Integer>` and `List<? extends Number>` are not (all listed types have the same erasure).

The key point is that sub-typing relationship between two provably distinct parametrized types with the same erasure is not possible in any way.

Sub-typing relationship between sub-types of two provably distinct parametrized types with the same erasure is also not possible in any way. If `S <: List<Integer>` and `T <: List<Number>` then castings `(T)S` and `(S)T` both are not possible even theoretically. So compiler complains.

## Extract 2.

Here is the example I came up with (compiles and runs without errors):

```
    static final class T extends ArrayList<Number>{
    }

    static T t;

    static List<?> l1 = new T();
    static List<? extends Number> l2 = new T();
    static List<String> l3;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        t = (T)l1;
        t = (T)l2;
//        t = (T)l3; //error
    }
```

You can see that `List<?>` and `List<? extends Number>` can be cast to final `T` while `T` does not (and can not) implement any of these interfaces.

`T <: List<Number>`. `List<Number>` is invocation of `List<E>` like `List<?>` and `List<? extends Number>`. `List<Number>` and `List<?>` and `List<? extends Number>` are not provably distinct (see above).

If we want to cast something of parametrized interface type `S` to final class type `T` this `T` **need not** explicitly or implicitly to implement `S`. But this `T` **must** to implement some another parametrized interface type which is in sub-type relationship with `S`. The key point is that sub-type relationship between parametrized types is defined not only by extending or implementing but also by type argument *containing*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## The first situation:

`ArrayList<String>` vs. `ArrayList<Integer>` have the same erasure, `ArrayList`, but are provably distinct because no `String` can ever be cast to an `Integer` and no `Integer` can ever be cast to a `String`.

## The second situation:

Let *G* be `List<T>` and *S* be `List<String>`. Suppose I have a class `MyFinalArrayList` like so:

```
public final class MyFinalIntArrayList extends ArrayList<Integer> {
    ...
}
```

and another like

```
public final class MyFinalStrArrayList extends ArrayList<String> {
    ...
}
```

I can cast the first to `List<Integer` and the second to `List<String`, but not vice versa.

Comment: So, parametrized types are provably distinct iff their type arguments are unrelated? OK. It seems like understanding is coming as of at least first extract: if two types have provably distinct parametrized super-types it means that these two types can not be in the same branch of hierarchy in any way.

Comment: As of Your answer about second extract. Casting of `MyFinalStrArrayList` to `List<String>` is trivial. I think You mean smth like: `List<Integer> li1 = new MyFinalIntArrayList(); MyFinalIntArrayList mfli1 = (MyFinalIntArrayList) li1;` This code compiles and runs because of `MyFinalIntArrayList` effectively implements `List<Integer>` by extending  `ArrayList<Integer>`. But I still can not get ideas into shape and understand exact meaning of second extract.

Comment: This JLS is really mindblowing.  Parametrized types are provably distinct iff their type arguments are **a)** not wildcards **and** not the same or **b)** wildcards **and** which bounds are not related.